# How to create model listener for virtual instance's create action in Liferay 7?

Tags: java, liferay, osgi, liferay-7

```
package com.test.model.listener;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

import com.google.gson.InstanceCreator;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.ModelListenerException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.BaseModelListener;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.ModelListener;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.User;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.*;

@Component(immediate = true, service = ModelListener.class)

public class InsertInstanceModelListener extends BaseModelListener<Instance??> {

    @Override
    public void onAfterCreate(Instance?? model) throws ModelListenerException {
        System.out.println("InsertInstanceModelListener.onAfterCreate()");
        super.onAfterCreate(model);
    }

}
```

I'm newbie of liferay.I think it's may be something like this,but don't know how to make it right.

Comment: What do you mean by action create an instance? Do you refer to a creation of a Liferay entity (eg. creating a User...) or you want to react to some lifecycle actions (eg. post logins, startup action)?

Comment: I have just learned about liferay 7.I'm gonna use liferay for multi-tenant,and create a virtual instance for each tenant.And I want to hook in instance create action,create a listener to get this instance id (company id) after create.Sorry if my English is bad.

Comment: did you verify your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on your way. This OSGi component needs to be specific,
you are probably looking for `com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.VirtualHost`
If I understood correctly.

You do not need to call supper though.

Comment: Victor thanks a lot. I solved my problem. It must be "company", but I mistook it for "virtualHost" .Here is correct codes :

`import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Company;


@Component(immediate = true, service = ModelListener.class)

public class InsertInstanceModelListener extends BaseModelListener<Company> {

 @Override
 public void onAfterCreate(Company model) throws ModelListenerException {
//some code
}`